# dnspython query hangs indefinetly(Intermittently)

Tags: python, dnspython

I have been using dnspython to run dig commands and get domain data info.
But sometimes, the python script just hangs on calling - dns.query.udp.

abstract code:

```
request = dns.message.make_query(domainName, dns.rdatatype.ANY)
response = dns.query.udp(request, '8.8.8.8')
```

I've even tried using multiple threads with a timeout but it still fails.